# How to add an empty option to a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to filter out some of my dropdown lists to only show items that are active. But at the same time i want to add an empty list item as the first and default option because not all dropdown lists will require a selection.

This is the code i have for making sure that i display active items but not sure how to add to it an empty list item feature as default.

```
IOrderedQueryable<VisitType> visitTypes = 
    _visitTypeRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(a => a.Description);

viewModel.VisitTypes = visitTypes
    .Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false)
    .ToSelectList("VisitTypeId", "Description", viewModel.VisitTypeId.ToString());
```

This is my VisitType code:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(VisitTypeMetadata))]
[ScaffoldTable(true)]
[LocalizedDisplayName("EntityNamePlural", NameResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entities.VisitType))]
[DisplayColumn("Description", "Description", false)]
public partial class VisitType
{

    public static VisitType All = new VisitType() { Description = "All", VisitTypeId = 0 };

    public string ValueDescription
    {
        get { return this.VisitTypeId.ToString() + "|" + Description; }
    }


    public class VisitTypeMetadata
    {
        [ColumnOrder(0)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Filter(Enabled = false)]
        [DefaultBoolean(Checked = true)]
        [DisplayName("Active")]
        public object IsActive { get; set; }

        [ColumnOrder((1))]
        public object Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public object VisitActivityEntries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please include your `VisitType` code as well.

Comment: @SteveDanner  added VisitType code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the answer to this question, it pretty much is a duplicate and answers exactly what you're looking for here

[Adding a default SelectListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894130/adding-a-default-selectlistitem)

```
return new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" } }.Concat(
       visitTypes
.Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false)
.ToSelectList("VisitTypeId", "Description", viewModel.VisitTypeId.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and link. I am sure this is very useful but because of how i am displaying items in the view model this code will require i little more work on my end to integrate with the rest of my code. I was hoping there might be a simple alteration to the code i already have.

Comment: try the edit I made, I simply copied their answer, I have modified it so it should work with your code above

Comment: Thank you for helping me out once again :) I got it working but instead of a return i changed it to viewModel.VisitTypes = new[].....

Comment: yup, that would make sense, sorry about that, missed that when I changed it around. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I have used SelectedIndex = -1; with good results in the past.