# Calling a controller function from onchange event in html view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm a new c# developer and I have a dropdownlist populated with string dates formatted like this:  "Jul 2017". There can be as many as 12 entries in the list.

When a user selects a date, I want to pass that selection to a controller method, convert it to a DateTime format and then use that date for further processing.

How do I pass the user selection to the controller so it can be converted and used? I've included commented out code below to show how I want to do the conversion. Getting the date to the controller is my challenge.

I've looked at similar questions on this site and they all seem overly complex (perhaps due to my naivete), but I was hoping for a more streamlined solution.

**Html View Code**

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectList", Model.ReverseMonthsLists())
```

**View Model Code**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ReverseMonthsLists()
    {
        var selectListItems = GetDates()
            .Select(_ => _.ToString("MMM yyyy"))
            .Select((dateString, index) => new SelectListItem 
                { Selected = index == 0, Text = dateString, Value = dateString })
            .ToList();
        return selectListItems;
    }

public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1).Date;
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    int numberOfMonthsToShow = (currentDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12 + 
        currentDate.Month - startDate.Month;
    var dates = new List<DateTime>(numberOfMonthsToShow);
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMonthsToShow; i++)
    {
        dates.Add(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
    }

    return dates;
}
```

**Controller function**

```
    public ActionResult Report_Performance()
    {
        //var newDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);  //<- Use newDate as parameter value into aVar to replace date at the end of the string
        var aVar = Models.Reporting.ListingStatsReportingViewModel.GetStats(userCurrentService.CompanyId.Value, Models.Reporting.DateTimePeriod.Monthly, DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1));
        return this.View(aVar);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to get a value to a controller is for the user to post the page back to the server, e.g. via a submit button. When this happens, the controller's action method can receive the selected item as an argument and then do what it needs to do. So if you just want the user to submit the form, and allow the web site to render the next page based on the selected value (and a list that you compute based on that value), that is all you need to do.

On the other hand, perhaps you don't want the user to submit the page; you want a series of dates to be displayed within the page, or for the dates to be processed by code running in the browser. If that is the case, I would suggest you perform the computations in Javascript within the browser itself, thereby avoiding the need for a round trip. Nothing in your `GetDates()` method requires any server side data, so it's just a question of converting your c# code to Javascript code.

In some rare cases, you will want a UX element on the page to get updated immediately based on a server computation, without the page being posted. If that is what you want, you'll have to use the AJAX solutions the other posters have provided. It's much more complicated and much more work. If you don't need that, use one of the solutions I provided above.

Comment: John Wu, I followed your suggestion and used the post back approach. But my selection isn't reflected on the screen. After the refresh, the list reverts back to the default selection. How do I fix this?

Comment: You will need to modify the view that renders the list to ensure that it preselects whatever value was submitted.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I don't know how to make it happen. Can you offer more specific guidance?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894130/adding-a-default-selectlistitem) which explains how a View can render a Select while setting the default item.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear. I read the answer but it doesn't address my issue. I already have a default item. When I select a new item, my code invokes a controller function to perform a bit of processing, and when the view is re-posts, the default item is selected again instead of the last selection I made. That's the selected item I'd like to see on the screen.

Comment: Maybe we're getting hung up on terminology.  The selected item IS the default item.  When you render the page again, the default item (the item that is selected by default when the page is displayed) should be the item the user selected.  So you just need to modify the code that sets the default item so that it looks at the user's selection, which should be available as part of the current HTTP request or as an input into the controller action. You can't keep both the original default item and the user's selection.

Comment: Do you have an article you can refer me to that shows how to do that?

Comment: Already linked the SO question that deals with it. If your situation is different, I suggest you post a new SO question so someone can provide a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was able to get it working following your guidance. It's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use The OnChange EventHandler For The HTML Select Option 
(The DropDownList ) To Start An Ajax Call To Your Controller , Simply Create a JavaScript Function That Preforms a Jquery Ajax Request Containing The User Selected Data To The Controller and Retrieve JSON From The Controller Using `Return Json()` Instead Of `Return View()` , Then Handle The Retrieved Data Using JavaScript , Your Controller Will Need To Accept a Parameter In Order To Receive The Data From The Ajax Request

Comment: Mostafa ELite, That sounds great. But as a newbie, I don't know the syntax well enough to do that. Can you point me to a concise reference source on the syntax for the OnChange EventHandler and a reference on precisely how to "preform a Jquery Ajax Request Containing The User Selected Data To The Controller"? I'll be happy to do the reading. But I've been bouncing around the Internet and this site for hours and getting a lot of confusing information.

Answer (score 1):

```
function SendDataToController (TheDropDownName){
       var DataToSend = $('#'+TheDropDownName).text();
       // Or Pass `this` From The Html When Assigning The Event Listener 
       // and Do Something Like var DataToSend = this.text();
        $.ajax({
          url: "@(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"))",
          data: DataToSend,
          success: function(ResponseFromController){
            //Do Stuff With Response 
          }
    });
}
```

This Will Send The Data To Controller So You Should Receive It in A Parameter

```
public ActionResult MyAction (string DataToSend)
{
  //Do Stuff With Data and Get a Json Object To Return 
   Return Json(JsonObject);
}
```

MVC Ajax Is Essential So You Should Learn It Before Tryin To Work On Any MVC Project, Also You Should Handle Request Error Using fail attr in The Ajax Setting But I Will Leave That To You